# How to display float and double values in 0,00E+00 form?

Tags: c#, .net

how to display float and double values in 0,00E+00 form? what CultureInfo is it?

Comment: One of many.  Usually the one that your user prefers.  You have to narrow it down a bit.  Pick, erm, German if you don't care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [exponential format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#EFormatString), not a CultureInfo.  Use the CultureInfo that your user wants.

```
double value = 12345.6789;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("E", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 1.234568E+004

Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("E10", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 1.2345678900E+004

Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("e4", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 1.2346e+004

Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("E", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR")));
// Displays 1,234568E+004
```